# Get data from collection gives a 'Cannot read property "button1" of undefined'

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, mongodb

I am trying to get 4 values from MongoDb collection when document is ready but it gives the 'Cannot read "button1" of undefined'.

```
ButtonsList = new Meteor.Collection('list');

$(document).ready(function(){
    var obj = ButtonsList.findOne({_id:'ZcLkjSwNGTpgHkoeq'});

    //button1 - button4 are fields that have some values
    var b1 = obj.button1;
    var b2 = obj.button2;
    var b3 = obj.button3;
    var b4 = obj.button4;

    console.log(b1);
    console.log(b2);
    console.log(b3);
    console.log(b4);
});
```

By the ways, it works when I click on a button but I would like to do when the page is loaded. Here is the working code when you click a button

```
'click .getRec': function(){

    var num = ButtonsList.findOne({_id:'ZcLkjSwNGTpgHkoeq'});

    var b1 = num.button1;
    var b2 = num.button2;
    var b3 = num.button3;
    var b4 = num.button4;
    console.log("button number is: "+b1);
    console.log("button number is: "+b2);
    console.log("button number is: "+b3);
    console.log("button number is: "+b4);
}
```

Comment: You mean ButtonsList isn't defined yet when the onready is performed? Also, I'm not sure what ButtonsList is or does, but I find it strange that the findOne function returns 4 buttons. Is that what's supposed to happen?

Comment: ButtonsList is a collection. I try to get data from object with id 'ZcLkjSwNGTpgHkoeq'. In this object I have 4 fields named: button1, button2, button3, button4 and try to get their values.